# Failure When Trying to Connect AWS Cognito to Auth0

Tags: amazon-cognito, auth0

I’m trying to connect a user pool in my AWS Cognito instance to Auth0 following the instructions in the [How do I set up Auth0 as a SAML identity provider with an Amazon Cognito user pool?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/auth0-saml-cognito-user-pool/) article.

When I click **Debug** from the **Addon: SAML2 Web App** section with the following settings…

**Application Callback URL**: https://{amazonCognitoDomain}.auth.{awsRegion}.amazoncognito.com/saml2/idpresponse

**Settings**

```
{
  "audience": "urn:amazon:cognito:sp:{cognitopoolId}",
  "mappings": {
    "email": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"
  },
  "nameIdentifierFormat": "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent"
}
```

… I’m taken to the following URL
`https://{subDomain}.auth0.com/login?state={someState}&client={auth0ClientId}&protocol=samlp&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmanage.auth0.com%2Ftester%2Fsamlp`

Which gives me this:
[image]

Opening the console I can see the error reported is…
`At least one email, sms or social connection needs to be available.`

[image]

I’ve also tried saving the settings and continuing on with the instructions in the article but got this same error when testing from Cognito.

I have one database connection enabled (see below) under the application’s Connections tab (which should store the email) and both the social and sms options are disabled.
[image]

Any help is very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You must configure an authentication source (a connection in Auth0).

You're configuring Cognito as a SAML SP and Auth0 as the IdP. Auth0 needs to be configured to authenticate users in some way.

If you are using your own database you need to ensure you are handling authentication through hooks (action scripts).

Comment: Andrew, thanks a bunch for the response. Can you give more details on what you mean by "You must configure an authentication source"? The only place I see to configure a "connection" is under the application in Auth0, and I have done that. See question - I've added a screenshot showing the datbase connection.

Comment: @JohnFisher Yeah that looks correct. It shouldn't be a single page application but I'm not sure if that could be issue. Select regular web app when you are creating it.

Comment: Makes sense that it would be regular web app since it's Cognito <--> Auth0 but I just tried regular web app and got the same issue. Also the video definitely says "choose Single Page Web Applications"